# form attempt to update while check multiple check boxes

Tags: jquery

When I am check multiple check boxes form jQuery dialog box form attempt to  update I used the below code:

```
 $(".chk").prop('checked', true);
```

and the same code when i click UncheckAll not removed checked attribute i used the below code

```
$('.chk:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
```

then i changed to

```
$(".chk").val(0);
$(".chk").removeAttr("checked"); 
console.log(this); //Here remove all checked attribute
```

but when i submit the form that form not updated the same thing click CheckAll working fine but UncheckAll not working
what is the problem

```
<input type="checkbox" class="chk" id="meters" name="Ids" value="0" ></input>
```

In my jps page multiple elements are there with name Ids i am expected array of Ids[0] in my form but the result is ids[2,3] like this 
I am using jquery 1.9.1 api

Comment: please search for answer before asking. lots of duplicates already exist.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('.chk:checked').removeAttr('checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $('.chk').removeAttr('checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.chk:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You code works fine.  The problem must be some where else in your code.

I've created a sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J7KdE/) for example.

**HTML:**

```
<input class="chk" checked type="checkbox" />
<input class="chk" checked type="checkbox" />
<input type="button" value="Click Me" />
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('input[type=button]').on('click', function () {
    $(".chk").prop('checked', false);
});
```

Hope you're trying something similar to this.